# find+grep fails

Tags: grep, find

I want to search the string "SEARCH" in all the .h files with command:

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec -Hw "SEARCH" { } \;
```

but it is throwing the error as:

```
find: â-Hwâ: No such file or directory, in linux
```

let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: just find the mistake what I have done; it should be ind . -name "*.h" -exec grep -Hw "SEARCH" { } \;

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` on `find` result:

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec grep "SEARCH" {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the 'grep' command.
Do this instead:

```
find . -type f -name "*.h" -exec grep -F -Hw "SEARCH" {} +
```

Note what I have changed:

- added `-type f`
- added the `grep -F` command
- changed `{ }` to `{}`, else it won't work
- changed `;` to a `+` (plus) at the end of the `-exec` statement, so that only one `grep` is executed for a bunch of files (speed up things, much more resource friendly)